# Capture an event After resizing the object of PPT slide

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I'm doing some development work on office powerpoint (2007, 2010, and 2013 versions) and looking for an event which will be triggered on resizing the object (like textbox) in PowerPoint Slide. I would like to capture this event in COM add-in coded in C# . Is there any way to achieve this? Please advise.

Thanks, Satish

Answer (score 0):

Yup,

read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227375.aspx

in your constructor or anywhere

```
Application.AfterShapeSizeChange += AfterShapeSizeChanged;
```

Then create a function

```
// Object "shape" is the one you currently edit
void AfterShapeSizeChange(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape)
{
    // do something
}
```

Note than this only works in PPT 2013. For previous versions(2007 or 2010) You may need to put more effort. I've implemented this approach by myself and have never found a better solution:

**1.** Create a proxy class for all of your shape object

**2.** Record the attributes (pos, width, and height), you need to compare the values you have with the current shape object

**3.** Create a Timer *(to create a similar function like thread but this one is synced with winform)*, check overtime, set it 15 times per second is good enough. only check the currently selected shape, don't check all shape you have in your ppt or it will be extremely slow

**4.** Combine with event WindowSelectionChange http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743918.aspx (this one is to cope with ctrl+z or ctrl+y, where users can do editing with undo or redo, thus editing shapes which are not on the currently selected slide). inside WindowSelectionChange() Similar to point 3, but now you need to check all shapes you have.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply and the valuable information. Yes, AfterShapeSizeChange event is only supported in PPT 2013. But I needed it for 2007 and 2010 as well. I tried but didn't get any solution. Is there any way to achieve this in 2007 and 2010 as well?

Comment: yep, it's in my answer

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! I understand your approach. Is there any code reference for this approach, please?

Comment: I do not own the code (it was a project in a company). I hope my answer is clear to understand, all you need to do is experimenting the windowselectionchanged event and c# timer

Comment: Ok, Thanks for sharing the approach. Much appreciated the prompt replies.